# Ввод матрицы символов

Tags: c

```
#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 5

void result_input(char game_result[][COLS]);


int main(void)
{
    char game_result[ROWS][COLS];
    result_input(game_result);

    return 0;
}


void result_input(char game_result[][COLS]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
            scanf("%s", game_result[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно ввести матрицу символов, но при вызове функции ввода выдает ошибку:

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2
>   has type 'int'

Проблема в несоответствии типов, хотя `game_result[i][j]` имеет тип `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `%s` (для строк) на `%c` (для ввода символов).

```
void result_input(char game_result[][COLS]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        for(j=0;j<COLS;j++){
            scanf("%c", &game_result[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: увы, аналогичная ошибка
`warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2  has type 'int' [-Wformat=]|`

Comment: @Hardc0re, функция ожидает указатель (по которому она будет писать извлечённый символ), а вы передаёте ей сам элемент массива. Добавьте взятие адреса: `scanf("%s", &game_result[i][j]);`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы выбрали неверный формат. Используйте формат `%c`

```
scanf(" %c", &game_result[i][j]);
      ^^^^  ^^^
```

В этом случае вам надо будет вводить символы через пробел.